# Extract single element from result output when applying a function to a list object

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lapply

I have the following list which includes a list of matrices:

```
dput(net.nulls.r2d)
 list(`plant-caterpillar` = list(structure(c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 17L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = 9:10), structure(c(0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 17L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = 9:10)), `caterpillar-parasitoid` = list(
structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(15L, 10L)), structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(15L, 
10L))))
```

I have the following function to calculate nestedness for each matrix using `nested.smdm`. The output for `nested.smdm` consists of a list of three values: `$WNODFrow`, `$WNODFcol`, `$WNODFmatrix`. I only want to extract values for `$WNODFmatrix`.

I have attempted the code below, however, it extracts the first element of the result list(`$WNODFrow`) and not the element I need to extract(`$WNODFmatrix`).

```
 net.null.nodf = function(nulls){
   net.null.metric <- list()
   for (i in 1:length(nulls)) {
   net.null.metric[[i]]= do.call('rbind', 
                               lapply(nulls[[i]], nest.smdm, weighted=TRUE))
     }
   names(net.null.metric) <- webs.names
   return(net.null.metric)
   }
```

How do I update the code above to specify the value of the `nest.smdm` result I would like to extract?

I have also tried:

```
net.null.nodf = function(nulls){
   net.null.metric <- list()
   for (i in 1:length(nulls)) {
   net.null.metric[[i]][3]= do.call('rbind', # In this line I added [3]
                               lapply(nulls[[i]], nest.smdm, weighted=TRUE))
     }
   names(net.null.metric) <- webs.names
   return(net.null.metric)
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how exactly your output should look like but something like this should do  it:

```r
library(purrr)
library(bipartite)

map(
  net.nulls.r2d, 
  ~map(
    map(.x, 
        nest.smdm, 
        weighted=TRUE
    ), 
    "WNODFmatrix"
  )
)
```

Note that `purrr::map()` can be used like `lapply()` to apply a function to each element of a list on the one hand and to extract a certain node from a list on the other hand.